# React / PyFlask - Proper Microsoft AD Login Architecture

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

**Summary**:
I'm currently working on a login flow for my React / Flask Web App.
The React Frontend is running on a Docker container exposing port `80` while Flask Backend API is running on a separate container on port `5000`.

The backend has an endpoint `GET /auth/login` that returns `Status:302` along with the redirect URL of Microsoft Login Page that the user completes acquiring a token. The token is then stored in the Session for Graph API use.

Whenever the frontend requests `GET /auth/login`, the redirect is blocked by CORS policy.

**Q:**
What would be the proper approach and architecture for the login flow?
Should I put the token acquisition in frontend and store the token in local storage?

Answer (score 4):

The typical approach for an application like this (JS front-end + API) is to use implicit grant flow in the front-end with MSAL.js and use JWT Bearer token authentication on the API.

So:

1. Your front-end React app needs to use MSAL.js to authenticate the user and acquire an access token for the API
2. This access token should then be added as a header to each request to the API (e.g. `Authorization: Bearer token-goes-here`
3. The API checks the token signature etc. is valid (use a library for this) and authenticates the user based on the token

Comment: Thanks juunas! Will try it out and do some refactor